# Character dissapears when it should be animating

Tags: python, animation, pygame

```
import pygame
pygame.init()

win = pygame.display.set_mode((1280,800))
pygame.display.set_caption("Fight")

appwallpaper = pygame.image.load('/Users/arnav/Downloads/AppWallpaper.jpeg') #setting 
the apps wallpaper storing it in a variable

pygame.display.set_icon(appwallpaper) #setting the apps wallpaper as the poster

walkLeft = [pygame.image.load('/Users/arnav/Downloads/Jokerattack1.png'), 
pygame.image.load('/Users/arnav/Downloads/Jokerattack2.png'), 
pygame.image.load('/Users/arnav/Downloads/Jokerattack3.png')]
walkRight = [pygame.image.load('/Users/arnav/Downloads/Jokerattack1Right.png'), 
pygame.image.load('/Users/arnav/Downloads/Jokerattack2Right.png'), 
pygame.image.load('/Users/arnav/Downloads/Jokerattack3Right.png')]

walkLeft2 = [pygame.image.load('/Users/arnav/Downloads/Jokerattack1.png'), 
pygame.image.load('/Users/arnav/Downloads/Jokerattack2.png'), 
pygame.image.load('/Users/arnav/Downloads/Jokerattack3.png'), 
pygame.image.load('/Users/arnav/Downloads/Jokerattack4.png')]
walkRight2 = [pygame.image.load('/Users/arnav/Downloads/Jokerattack1Right.png'), 
pygame.image.load('/Users/arnav/Downloads/Jokerattack2Right.png'), 
pygame.image.load('/Users/arnav/Downloads/Jokerattack3Right.png'), 
pygame.image.load('/Users/arnav/Downloads/Jokerattack4Right.png')] 

Joker1 = pygame.image.load('/Users/arnav/Downloads/Joker.png')
char = pygame.transform.scale(Joker1, (100, 165)) 
bg1 = pygame.image.load('/Users/arnav/Downloads/fighterbackground.png')
bg = pygame.transform.scale(bg1, (1280, 800))
x = 50
y = 550
width = 40
height = 60
vel = 5

clock = pygame.time.Clock()

isJump = False
jumpCount = 10

left = False
right = False
space = False
walkCount = 0

currentWalk = walkLeft

def redrawGameWindow():
    global walkCount

    win.blit(bg, (0,0))  
    if walkCount + 1 >= 9:
        walkCount = 0
    
    if left:  
        currentWalk = walkLeft
        win.blit(currentWalk[walkCount//3], (x,y))
        walkCount += 1   
    elif right:
        currentWalk = walkRight
        win.blit(currentWalk[walkCount//3], (x,y))
        walkCount += 1
    elif space:
        win.blit(bg, (0,0))  
        if walkCount + 1 >= 12:
            walkCount = 0        
            currentWalk = walkLeft2
            win.blit(currentWalk[walkCount//3], (x,y))
            walkCount += 1
    else:
        win.blit(char, (x, y))
        walkCount = 0
    
    pygame.display.update() 



run = True

while run:
    clock.tick(27)

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False

    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()

    if keys[pygame.K_LEFT] or keys[ord('a')] and x > vel: 
        x -= vel
        left = True
        right = False
        space = False
        currentWalk = walkLeft

    elif keys[pygame.K_RIGHT] or keys[ord('d')] and x < 1000 - vel - width:  
        x += vel
        left = False
        right = True
        space = False
        currentwalk = walkRight
    
    else: 
        left = False
        right = False
        space = False
        walkCount = 0
    
    if not(isJump):
        if keys[pygame.K_UP] or keys[ord('w')]:
            isJump = True
            left = False
            right = False
            space = False
            walkCount = 0
    else:
        if jumpCount >= -10:
            y -= (jumpCount * abs(jumpCount)) * 0.5
            jumpCount -= 1
        else: 
            jumpCount = 10
            isJump = False

    if keys[ord('n')]:   
        x -= vel
        left = False
        right = False 
        space = True
        currentWalk = walkLeft2    
    
    if keys[ord('z')]:   
        x -= vel
        left = False
        right = False 
        space = True
        currentWalk = walkLeft2   
        
    if x <= 0:
        x = 0
    elif x >= 1100:
        x = 1100

    

    redrawGameWindow() 

def redrawgamewindow2():   
    currentWalk = walkLeft2

    win.blit(bg, (0,0))  
    if walkCount + 1 >= 12:
        walkCount = 0
    
    if left:  
        win.blit(currentWalk[walkCount//3], (x,y))
        walkCount += 1   
    elif right:
        win.blit(walkRight[walkCount//3], (x,y))
        walkCount += 1
    else:
        win.blit(char, (x, y))
        walkCount = 0    
    
    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()

    if keys[pygame.K_SPACE]:        
        currentWalk = True
        
        pygame.display.update()     



pygame.quit()
```

In this program, I have 2 animations and I am using currentWalk to differentiate and use both animations. I have used walkCount to animate and most parts of the program are working and it is running fine, problem is that when I press Z or N to animate walkLeft2, it doesnt animate and instead dissapears. When I let go it reeapears and you can see that it moved left but the actual movement isnt visible.

Answer (score 0):

It is a matter of [Indentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html):

```py
def redrawGameWindow():
    # [...]

    elif space:
        win.blit(bg, (0,0))  
        if walkCount + 1 >= 12:
            walkCount = 0 

        # INDENTATION
        #<--|       
        currentWalk = walkLeft2
        win.blit(currentWalk[walkCount//3], (x,y))
        walkCount += 1
```